# Can I delete data records or shards from amazon Kinesis without deleting stream?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I know data records in Kinesis Stream will be deleted automatically in 24 hrs. But in my application when ever I write some data into stream, for the 2nd time if I want to write some other data, Data inserted first should be deleted. Please anyone help me since I am new to using AWS Kinesis Stream...I didn't get any help from Kinesis Service API...

Comment: add some more tag please

Comment: A fact to know - You can't delete the data even if you delete the stream. You can create the stream back with the same name and all the data will be there as per your previously defined retention period on stream.

Comment: We can delete the dynamodb table which has entry of last checkpoint. If there will be no table than by default it will start reading from LATEST entry. So it doesn't need to delete data from kinesis stream. Although it will be automatically deleted after retention period. Try these.  Note - cautiously delete the table

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not delete previously inserted data from stream, but you can read data using KCL.
KCL will create checkpoint every after one data slot read, so whenever you go for next slot of new data, KCL will read it from last checkpoint created in dynamodb table, so previously read data will be not included in next slot.

Comment: To be clear, "SequenceNumber" is the nomenclature the Kinesis documentation and API seem to use for these checkpoints.